# Why does echo "$ZDOTDIR" return nothing?

Tags: files, zsh, environment-variables

### Background

In Chapter 5 of the [ZSH manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files) it states:

> Commands are first read from `/etc/zshenv`; this
> cannot be overridden...Commands are then read from
> `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`.

### Issue

I wanted to view what the `$ZDOTDIR` variable contained. So I used:

```
$ echo "$ZDOTDIR"
```

However, no value was returned. Why is this happening? Or am I missing something?

Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the manual that you link to:

> If  `ZDOTDIR`  is unset, `HOME` is used instead.

This means that if your `ZDOTDIR` variable is unset, *and it is usually unset*, the `HOME` variable's value will be used in its place, so when the manual refers to, e.g., `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`, this would be the file `$HOME/.zshrc`.

I personally set `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.zsh` in my `$HOME/.zshenv` file.   I then have `.zprofile` and `.zshrc` etc. in my `$HOME/.zsh` directory.